# Selenoid Chrome 113th version is redirecting local URLs to HTTPS, how can I open them in HTTP protocol?

Tags: java, docker, google-chrome, automated-tests, selenoid

Can't work in 113th version of Chrome in Selenoid image with HTTP-protocol

Hi all!
I have UI Automation Java project, which work on local Docker Containers with Selenoid and Chrome browser, and have a problem with Selenoid Chrome image version 113.
I have a local server with some pictures, which I use in my local site. When I try to open local URL with this picture, I get a an error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, because links opened in HTTPS protocol, but I expect open this URL in HTTP protocol.
As I understand, in new version of Chrome add some option which make redirect to HTTPS protocol by default.
I found in Internet some fix, as add new argument in Chrome options
`chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-features=RedirectToHttps");`
But its not work.

All tests in 112-th version working correctly.
I will be grateful for your help.